# How to specify that I want Node to use Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, darwin

I'm on a windows machine however my node is set to Darwin. Is there a command to switch ?

It's stopping me from adding a windows service and is erroring with:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'os-service'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Fusiozii\REST-API\rest.js:25:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Node = v6.11.2

Node-gyp = v3.4.0

[image]

Comment: *I'm on a windows machine however my node is set to Darwin* - what does this mean?

Comment: When I ran an npm install, it came up with something like version: Darwin (linux) but im  using a windows machine so obviously i dont want Darwin

Comment: @estus I've added a picture

Comment: The problem is specific to the project where you run `npm install` which you don't show. The problem isn't anything like your description. The error clearly shows that OS is detected correctly. `fsevents` is Darwin package and shouldn't be installed in other OSes. It should be optional dep, and in your case it likely isn't.

Comment: I don't understand where its getting the default os from though?

Comment: There's no such thing as default OS. It detects that fsevent dependency is incompatible with OS you're using (Windows) and exits with an error.